# Why doesn't StringReader.Read() return a byte?

Tags: java, char, ascii, byte, stringreader

I was using StringReader in a Data Structures assignment (Huffman codes), and was testing if the end of the string had been reached. I found that the int value that StringReader.read() returns is not -1, but 65535, so casting the result to a byte solved my infinite loop problem I was having.

Is this a bug in JDK, or is it common practice to cast values returned from Reader.read() calls to bytes? Or am I missing something?

The gist of my code was something like this:

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader("This is a test string");
char c;
do {
    c = sr.read();
//} while (c != -1);     //<--Broken
} while ((byte)c != -1); //<--Works
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact that doesn't even compile. I get:

> *Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to char*

Since the [`sr.read()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html#read%28%29) call returns an `int` I suggest you store it as such.

This compiles (and works as expected):

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader("This is a test string");
int i;               // <-- changed from char
do {
    i = sr.read();

    // ... and if you need a char...
    char c = (char) i;

} while (i != -1);   // <-- works :-)
```

---

> **Why doesn't StringReader.Read() return a byte?**

Strings are composed of 16-bit unicode characters. These won't fit in an 8-bit byte. One could argue that a `char` would have been enough, but then there is no room for providing an indication that the EOF is reached.

Comment: ` char c = (char) -1;      System.out.println(c!=-1);` compiles for me

Comment: If you have a variable `char c` (as the OP does), then `c = sr.read();` (as the OP also has) won't compile.

Comment: The string width problem makes sense, I had to change the base case of my recursive method around, and I just tested without casting to (byte) and all is well again >_<. Here now is an opportunity to learn more . . .

Comment: Oh and side note, forgetting to cast as char was a typo, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

`StringReader#read` returns an `int` value which is `-1` if the end of the stream has been reached.

The problem in your code is that you already convert the `int` value to a char and test the char:

```
System.out.println("Is it still (-1)?: " + (int) ((char) -1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Characters in java are 2 bytes because they're encoded in UTF-16. This is why read() returns an int, because byte is not large enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
 char c = (char) -1;
        System.out.println(""+c);
        System.out.println(""+(byte)c);
```

This code will solve your doubt ..

Answer (score 1):

A Java `String` is a sequence of `chars` which are not bytes but values that represent UTF-16 code-points. The semantics of `read` is to return the next *atom* from the input stream. In case of a `StringReader` the *atomic component* is a 16-bit value which cannot be represented as a single byte.